# Can't hide footer on non-home pages

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to hide the footer from non-home pages. Below is what I have tried, **[This is the website](http://emgraphics.net/necawp)**

```
.home #first  {
    width:950px;
    margin-top:20px ;
    border-top: 1px dotted #9bacd4;
    background:#ff0000;
}


.home #first img {
    margin:5px;
}

.home #first h3
{
   font-size:16px;
   font-weight:bold;
   margin:5px 0px 15px 15px;    
}

#first {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: css isn't "smart". it doesn't know (and doesn't care) which page you're on. it's up to you to provide the hints/rules to establish that. if you want to change rules for the homepage, you have to put in the class/css rules/stylesheets that apply only to that page, e.g. maybe `body#homepage #footer { display: none }` only put that #homepage ID on the actual homepage body tag.

Comment: Since it's wordpress site you can check if it's a home page.  Check out the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Comment: @Marc B and [at] Uriah James Rittenhouse: he already has class `.home` on the body tag; but checking on the backend via `is_home()` would be the better solution, as it saves bandwidth.

Comment: @feela: not everything is a wordpress site...

Comment: @MarcB look at the source, this one is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your CSS rules `.home #first` and `#first` are used. If you have overlapping properties, the most specific wins. So in this case add `display:block` to `.home #first` selector and it will override the `display:none`, as `.home #first` is more specific.

Comment: Works like a charm.  I would never have thought of that.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should set it to hidden first and then display it on a specific condition, for example on the homepage:

```
/* hide for all pages */
#first {
    display: none;
}

/* but display it on the homepage */
.home #first {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put a class in the  tag of your home page that says something like .

Assuming your footer block has something like  or  you could then use CSS to specify that the footer is only visible on the Home Page.

```
.footer {display:none;}
.home .footer {display:block;}
```

Should work!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `is_home()` function reference to control where you display your footer.
[Read the documentation.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)